# Manipulate 'font-family' via user script

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, google-chrome-extensions, css

I would like to restrict the set of fonts available in web browser (chrome on GNU/Linux in my case) to `monospace`, `serif` and `sans-serif` only. The first step was to install the browser extension «uBlock Origin» which can prevent web sites from loading external fonts. Alas it does not help much: there are many fonts families still available.

How can I replace the fonts to the three above mentioned by some other extension (maybe Stylus or Tampermonkey?). The idea is to create a mapping of available font families to the three standard and somehow change 'font-family' attributes on all web sites.

PS. I'm not sure the **superuser** is the right place for this question: it's not really about system administration. Which stack exchange site could be a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

First install tempermonkey
[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en);

Then add this script

```
document.body.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
```

or,
install stylish [stylish- chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en)

then add this line

```
font-family:"sans-serif";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).